# how to get youtube transcript from any video

Tags: node.js, api, express, npm

I'm trying to get any youtube transcript from a given url.

Im using runkit npm to try : https://npm.runkit.com/youtube-transcript using the npm youtube transcript https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-transcript
so my code on runkit is :

```
var youtubeTranscript = require("youtube-transcript")
youtubeTranscript.fetchTranscript('_cY5ZD9yh2I').then(console.log);
```

and I have the error :

```
TypeError: youtubeTranscript.fetchTranscript is not a function
```

Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with runkit? Have you tried running it in your local node?

Comment: I think runkit is working fine it's just something missing in my 2 lines code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you try this?

```
const youtubeTranscript = require('youtube-transcript');
youtubeTranscript.default.fetchTranscript('_cY5ZD9yh2I').then(console.log);
```

Comment: TypeError: yt.automatic is not a function

Comment: youtubeTranscript.default.fetchTranscript('_cY5ZD9yh2I')......

Comment: It's working, Thanks ! How did you find the default

Comment: Just print youtubeTranscript object

Comment: lib does `export default`, follow the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-transcript) `import YoutubeTranscript from 'youtube-transcript';` and you won't need to use default

Comment: And how can I set a language if I want to grab the french or the english transcript ? @LawrenceCherone

Comment: @TaronQalashyan

Comment: I find it all good !

Comment: youtubeTranscript.default.fetchTranscript('_cY5ZD9yh2I', { lang:'fr'}).then(console.log);

but you video should has french transcript support